# Retrieve Organization share statiscts Time bound error

Tags: python-3.x, linkedin-api

In linkedin api, I'm able to retrieve organization statistics for the lifetime ,But for time bound I'm getting error. I followed the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?tabs=http

I used  encoded url like

api_url = [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A{id}&timeIntervals=%28timeRange%3A%28start%3A1551398400000%2Cend%3A1552003200000%29%2CtimeGranularityType%3ADAY%29](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A%7Bid%7D&timeIntervals=%28timeRange%3A%28start%3A1551398400000%2Cend%3A1552003200000%29%2CtimeGranularityType%3ADAY%29)

but I'm getting error

```
{
  "message": "Parameter 'timeIntervals' is invalid",
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are passing in `timeIntervals` instead of `timeRange.start` per the [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?tabs=http#schema). Also `timeRange.start` should be a long int value representing not a `timeRange` URN.

Example:

```
timeRange.start=1654117775000
```

Comment: yes, i made a api call without encoding URN, it worked....